# form name array not working

Tags: javascript, php, html

What could be causing my array from not forming correctly? I get the following result.

```
array(1) {
   ["element[119"]=>
   array(1) {
     ["data"]=>
     string(1) "0"
   }
 }
```

When it the result should look like this.

```
array(1) {
  ["element"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["119"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["data"]=>
      string(1) "0"
    }
  }
}
```

Simplified front end:

```
<input class="custom-control-input data is-valid" data-parent="0" data-qid="119" name="element[119][data]" id="119-Yes" type="radio" onchange="showTextBox(this)" value="1" checked="">

<script type="text/javascript">
var formData = {};
          $(form).find(":input.data:visible, input[type=hidden].data").each(function (index, node) {
              formData[node.name] = node.value;
          });
          console.log(formData);
$.ajax({
            url: "index.php?route=form/form/saveSection",
            data: { form_id: $("#formRequest").data("formsaveid"), section_id: $("#formRequest").data("currentsectionid"), path: $("#formRequest").data("formpath"), action: "saveSection", data: formData},
            dataType: "json",
            method: "POST",
            beforeSend: function() {
              console.log("Saving Section...");
              console.log("Section ID: "+$("#formRequest").data("currentsectionid"));
              console.log(postData);
            },
            success: function(data) {
            }
          });
</script>
```

Simplified back end:

```
var_dump($data);exit;
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is happening with the way you manipulate the data with

```
$(form).find(":input.data:visible, input[type=hidden].data").each(function (index, node) {
      formData[node.name] = node.value;
});
```

really you need to serialize the entire form and convert it to json, so replace the above with this:

```
var formData = JSON.parse($(form).serializeArray());
```

Then you can:

```
<?php
    var_dump($_POST['data']);
```

Comment: That way isn't dynamic. My way I can add infinite depth to the array. It has something to do with post call from php. The json data saved into the post is `{element[119][data]:"0"}`

Comment: Your way doesn’t add infinite depth because it is setting your name keys incorrectly. What you actually need is to recursively look at these brackets in the field name and create a new depth if you need it to be dynamic. My example here just solves the problem you posed. I’ll re-do this shortly

Comment: Okay. It pretty much needs to emulate what happens when submitting a form. Instead using ajax. I would have assumed the post data looks exactly the same (name: value), but obviously doesn't since it isn't working.

Comment: I've updated the answer which should now solve your problem, sorry for the delay.

Comment: Have you tested my way? The reason why it is breaking is because your loop isn’t doing what you think it is.

Comment: Yes serializeArray does not create an array. All that does is assigns name and value to an array. That is not what I want. My way works if i change the name from name="element[119][data]" to name="element][119][data]"

Comment: So to clarify this question originally is asking why I am a getting a random "[" at the beginning of either the json output to php or the php translation.

Comment: Yes and I am answering by saying that by having brackets in the name, when you do `formData[node.name] = node.value;` You are basically saying: `formData["element[119][data]"] = node.value` which is wrong because that would make "element[119][data]" the entire single key name and not generate sub-array. If you serialize the form, when PHP receives it the other end it will have the sub-arrays in there. STOP thinking you need to use a loop YOU DON'T

Comment: Based on the two examples of PHP output at the start of the question. Serialisation is CLEARLY what you want.

Comment: Test it with my way and please demonstrate what your output is

Answer (score 0):

```
name="[element][119][data]"
```

Try to encapsulate everything inside array brackets in your name tag in HTML.

Comment: It just moves where this bracket issue is happening.`array(1) {
  ["[element"]=>
  array(1) {
    [119]=>
    array(1) {
      ["quantity"]=>
      string(1) "0"
    }
  }`